# Spring expression 4.0 jars

Tags: spring, spring-el

What are the jar files I need to use spring expression language in my web app?

This web app itself is not based on Spring. I would like to use the 4.0.1 version. Is spring-expression-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar alone enough?

Comment: Just add the jar, your compiler will tell you if something is missing. Your title is mentioning a different version than your text

Comment: Oops. Sorry for the different versions. It is 4.0.1. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you need the expression and the core jar. Try with expression only and add core if something still is missing.

And you should consider using 4.1 or even 4.2, 4.1 is available and has no higher requirements than 4.0. 4.2 is scheduled to be released in only a few weeks, so you could start with the already available RC2 and go to final very soon.

Comment: Thanks. That's my plan. I will update once I have tested.

Comment: Does it make sense to test with an old version and then go to the new one ? I would do my testing with the most current version available